# Raw types and subtyping

Tags: java, compiler-construction, raw-types

We have generic class

```
SomeClass<T>{ }
```

We can write the line:

```
SomeClass s= new SomeClass<String>();
```

It's ok, because raw type is supertype for generic type. But

```
SomeClass<String> s= new SomeClass();
```

is correct to. Why is it correct? I thought that type erasure was before type checking, but it's wrong.

#### From Hacker's Guide to Javac

> When the Java compiler is invoked with default compile policy it performs the following passes:
>
> 1. **parse:** Reads a set of *.java source files and maps the resulting token
>    sequence into AST-Nodes.
> 2. **enter:** Enters symbols for the definitions into the symbol table.
> 3. **process annotations:** If Requested, processes annotations found in
>    the specified compilation units.
> 4. **attribute:** Attributes the Syntax trees. This step includes name
>    resolution, type checking and constant folding.
> 5. **flow:** Performs data ow analysis on the trees from the previous step.
>    This includes checks for assignments and reachability.
> 6. **desugar:** Rewrites the AST and translates away some syntactic sugar.
> 7. **generate:** Generates Source Files or Class Files.

Generic is syntax sugar, hence type erasure invoked at 6 pass, after type checking, which invoked at 4 pass. I'm confused.

Comment: Generics are not syntactic sugar, SomeClass and SomeClass<Object> are subtly but different types. Assignment of a raw type to a generic one is allowed to support interop with the old code.

Comment: @ice-phoenix That explains it. But at what pass type erasure is invoked? At 2 or at 4 before type-checking?

Comment: Step 7, generics are dropped when the JVM bytecode is generated, the compiler always knows the full generic type of a variable.

Comment: @ice-phoenix _Step 7_ As i understand, it is not true. See http://www.oraclejavamagazine-digital.com/javamagazine/20120708?pg=52#pg52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type parameter definitely participate in type checking; otherwise it will be pointless (i.e. no better than raw types).

The information is also needed to generate implicit casts so it will survive to your step 7 and technically to runtime as debug symbols. However, only the erasure will participate in runtime type cast checking (for obvious backwards compatibility reasons). Nonetheless, if your generic code can be fully statically checked, it can be as strong as generic programs in non-type-erasure languages.

When you assign `SomeClass` to `SomeClass<String>`, the compiler will give you a warning about raw type use. At this point, your program is obviously no longer safe.

Comment: I think, that it is step 4, just after type checking. See http://www.oraclejavamagazine-digital.com/javamagazine/20120708?pg=52#pg52